Is the "let" operation in TikZ valid only when using "let -in"?
I am just getting started with TikZ package for drawing figures.
I have created a bunch of points which are parametrized and dependent on each other. This is the code:
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[intersections, calc, through, backgrounds]

\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{TikZ Test}

    % thickness
    \def \BLThickness{1}
    
    % example domain coefficients for figure drawing
    \def \ACoeff{3}
    \def \BCoeff{5}
    \def \CCoeff{5}
    \def \DCoeff{4}
    \def \ECoeff{2}
    
    % csutom commands to be used in tikz package only
    \newcommand {\PointText}[1]{ {\scriptsize #1} }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        
        % the grid
        %\draw[help lines] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
        
        % the origin
        \coordinate [label=below:\PointText{Origin}] (origin) at (0,0);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (origin) circle (3pt);
        
        % P1 
        \coordinate [label=left:\PointText{P1}] (P1) at ($(origin)-\BCoeff*(1,0) $);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P1) circle (3pt);
        
        % P2
        \coordinate [label=below:\PointText{P2}] (P2) at ($(origin) + \CCoeff*(1,0)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P2) circle (3pt);
        
        %P3
        \coordinate [label=below right:\PointText{P3}] (P3) at ($(P2) + \BLThickness*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P3) circle (3pt);

        %P4
        \coordinate [label=left:\PointText{P4}] (P4) at ($(P1) + \BLThickness*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P4) circle (3pt);
    
        %P5
        \coordinate [label=above:\PointText{P5}] (P5) at ($(P2) + \BLThickness*(0,1) + \ACoeff*(0,1) + \DCoeff*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P5) circle (3pt);

        %P6
        \coordinate [label=above:\PointText{P6}] (P6) at ($(P1) + \BLThickness*(0,1) + \ACoeff*(0,1) + \DCoeff*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P6) circle (3pt);        
        
        %P7
        \coordinate [label=below:\PointText{P7}] (P7) at ($(P2) + \ECoeff*(1,0)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P7) circle (3pt);

        %P8
        \coordinate [label=right:\PointText{P8}] (P8) at ($(P7) + \BLThickness*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P8) circle (3pt);

        %P9
        \coordinate [label:above:\PointText{P9}] (P9) 
            let
                \p1 = (P7), \p2 = (P5)
            at ( \x1,\y2);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P9) circle (3pt);

        % source 
        \coordinate [label=below right:\PointText{Source}] (source) at ($(origin) + \BLThickness*(0,1) + \ACoeff*(0,1)$);
        \fill [red,opacity=0.5] (source) circle (3pt);
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

When I include the commands for P9, TeXstudio shows the error:
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \end{frame}

Is the "let- at" operation valid in this approach? My goal is to define the coordinate of P9 whose X-coordinate is the X-coordinate of P7 and, the Y-coordinate is the Y-coordinate of P5.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I added the compliable code.

Unrelated to the problem, but you don't need to load the default themes. They are, as the name suggests, the default.

There are ways to use the functionality as part of a coordinate's option.

In your case, you are looking for the coordinate (P7|-P5) by the way, no calc needed.

You can use a \path to combine let and creating a coordinate:
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, through, backgrounds, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{TikZ Test}

    % thickness
    \def \BLThickness{1}
    
    % example domain coefficients for figure drawing
    \def \ACoeff{3}
    \def \BCoeff{5}
    \def \CCoeff{5}
    \def \DCoeff{4}
    \def \ECoeff{2}
    
    % csutom commands to be used in tikz package only
    \newcommand {\PointText}[1]{ {\scriptsize #1} }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        
        % the grid
        %\draw[help lines] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
        
        % the origin
        \coordinate [label=below:\PointText{Origin}] (origin) at (0,0);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (origin) circle (3pt);
        
        % P1 
        \coordinate [label=left:\PointText{P1}] (P1) at ($(origin)-\BCoeff*(1,0) $);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P1) circle (3pt);
        
        % P2
        \coordinate [label=below:\PointText{P2}] (P2) at ($(origin) + \CCoeff*(1,0)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P2) circle (3pt);
        
        %P3
        \coordinate [label=below right:\PointText{P3}] (P3) at ($(P2) + \BLThickness*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P3) circle (3pt);

        %P4
        \coordinate [label=left:\PointText{P4}] (P4) at ($(P1) + \BLThickness*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P4) circle (3pt);
    
        %P5
        \coordinate [label=above:\PointText{P5}] (P5) at ($(P2) + \BLThickness*(0,1) + \ACoeff*(0,1) + \DCoeff*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P5) circle (3pt);

        %P6
        \coordinate [label=above:\PointText{P6}] (P6) at ($(P1) + \BLThickness*(0,1) + \ACoeff*(0,1) + \DCoeff*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P6) circle (3pt);        
        
        %P7
        \coordinate [label=below:\PointText{P7}] (P7) at ($(P2) + \ECoeff*(1,0)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P7) circle (3pt);

        %P8
        \coordinate [label=right:\PointText{P8}] (P8) at ($(P7) + \BLThickness*(0,1)$);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P8) circle (3pt);

        %P9
        \path let \p1 = (P7), \p2 = (P5) in coordinate[label=above:\PointText{P9}] (P9) at ( \x1,\y2);
        \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (P9) circle (3pt);

        % source 
        \coordinate [label=below right:\PointText{Source}] (source) at ($(origin) + \BLThickness*(0,1) + \ACoeff*(0,1)$);
        \fill [red,opacity=0.5] (source) circle (3pt);
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thanks. This works. However, what's the trick here (if any)?

@ishan_ae There is no trick. Everything in TikZ is placed on a \path. The macro \coordinate is just \path coordinate.

Got it. Thanks.

@ishan_ae what the TikZpert said in the comment above :)
